# Take photo immediately after changing camera type with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to take a photo using react native camera immediately after changing from back to front camera. To give you an idea, the code looks kind of like this:

```
state = {
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back
}

takePicture = () => {
    const options = {quality:0.5}
    this.setState({type:Camera.Constants.Type.front}, () => {
        this.camera.takePictureAsync(options).then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        });
    })
};
```

I presumed that the photo I would have taken would be the one with the front facing camera. However, the photo i get is always the one with the back facing camera. Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your render method, are you including the type as an attribute?

```
<Camera ... type={this.state.type} />
```

Comment: yeah, didn't bother to include that in the question sorry